# How can I remove library code calls from pytest traceback?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, pytest

I'm using pytest with mock in my python project.

When I get a test failure that involves a mock object (almost all of them), the traceback dives into the mock library source code and my code that's actually triggering the failure often scrolls out of view.

Is there a way to tell py.test to exclude installed libraries from the traceback or something like that? The noise level is taking away from what is otherwise a sweet testing library.

Answer (score 7):

There is a hack: a function defining the local variable `__tracebackhide__` will not be shown.  Example:

```
def some_support_code(x, y):
    __tracebackhide__ = True
    assert x == y
```

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I wonder how I would make that work in my situation, to hide all mock library calls?

Comment: Add `__tracebackhide__ = True` in the most common functions of your mock library.  If you prefer something more general you can always hack py.test directly.

Comment: Ah, but mock is a standard Python library, installed via `pip install mock`, not code I've developed myself. What I'd be looking for is a way to exclude any "library" code that I don't own, perhaps by pytest detecting that it was installed in `site-package/` or whatever and excluding it, i.e. treating it as a "black box", as I do.

Answer (score 3):

[`pytest-mock`](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) includes a feature that will hide tracebacks from the mock library. Just install `pytest-mock` and you're done.